# Using a hex string as an address variable

Tags: python, hex, i2c, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to create a few I2C objects for my raspberry pi and want to cycle through addresses `0x48..0x4B`. However I can't figure out how to send the hex address value to the method properly. To simplify things, here is the code just trying to send the first value:

```
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
address_as_int = 72
address_as_hex = hex(address_as_int)
print (address_as_hex) # returns 0x48 like it's suppose to
try:
    ads0 = ADS.ADS1115(i2c, address = address_as_hex) # Errors out
except:
    print(f"Didn't find a device on {address_as_hex}") # Didn't find a device on 0x48
```

But running this:

```
ads0 = ADS.ADS1115(i2c, address = 0x48)
```

finds my device.

My guess is that the method is seeing `address_as_hex` as a string and not a hex number, but even if I declare the string a hex number like this

```
ads0 = ADS.ADS1115(i2c, address = hex(address_as_hex))
```

It still doesn't see it as a proper hex address.

Comment: Don't convert the integer to a string with `hex()`. `ads0 = ADS.ADS1115(i2c, address = address_as_int)` will work. The last line, `ads0 = ADS.ADS1115(i2c, address = 0x48)` is exactly the same as `ads0 = ADS.ADS1115(i2c, address = 72)` because `0x48 == 72`.

Comment: You should understand that `72` and `0x48` are two ways of representing the same value. The Python interpreter evaluate them to the same value. One is base 10 and one is base 16. We use both because sometimes one is more convenient than the other.

Comment: `hex()` returns a **string** containing the (Python) hexadecimal representation of the numeric value passed to it. But it's very doubtful that what you want to pass as the address argument. In Python program *code*, an integer numeric value can be represented as either `72` or `0x48` (or even `0b1001000` in binary) — they're all ways of expressing the same quantity.

Comment: …so, you could cycle through that range of addresses with either `for address in range(72, 76)` or `for address in range(0x48, 0x4C)`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  YES! Every time I run across trouble in Python I've learned it generally the easiest, most sensible answer. Thanks

Comment: @martineau Yes. It's always the easiest way in Python. Thanks